# Measure to SUM of more recent values using DAX from PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to `SUM` the values of more recent dates, which are the more recent?

[image]

The `MEASURE` needs return the following value: **27**

Why **27**?

Because it's the SUM of more recent values from which `idOp`.

- 100 - (2017-07-12) - 10
- 101 - (2017-07-14) - 2
- 102 - (2017-07-05) - 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Latest Date Sum = SUMX(VALUES(Data[idOp])
                  , CALCULATE(SUM(Data[value])
                    , LASTNONBLANK(Data[Date]
                      , CALCULATE(SUM(Data[value]))
                      )
                    )
                  )
```

Comment: Can you explain it? What part of your code chooses the most recent value of each partition by idOP?

Comment: If you start out with the "inner measure" : CALCULATE(SUM(Data[value]), LASTNONBLANK(Data[Date], CALCULATE(SUM(Data[value])))); This DAX will obtain the most recent record in the date column using LATNONBLANK, for the ENTIRE table and calculate sum of all values with that date. SUMX returns the sum of an expression evaluated for each row in a table.Wrapping the original "inner measure" in SUMX and opening up the filter context to all partitions of IdOp is how I was able to obtain the sum for the most recent dates. I hope that helps!!